# Are prototypes needed in JavaScript, when we have closures?

Tags: javascript, class, closures, prototype

I have been working as a web developer for 3 years. I have only very seldom created my own prototypes for objects (I guess I also created prototypes via the new ES 6 class syntax).

Whenever I can do something with a prototype:

```
function Client(host, port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}

Client.prototype.httpRequestHelper = function(body) {
    ...
};

var client = new Client('http://127.0.0.1', 8801);
```

using closures instead has worked just fine, and has been the preferred approach because more people understand that approach well (me included):

```
function createClient(host, port) {
    function httpRequestHelper(body) {
        ...
    }

    return {
        httpRequestHelper
    }
}

var client = createClient('http://127.0.0.1', 8801);
```

What are the benefits of using prototypes (and ES6 classes) over closures? Why are they needed?

Answer (score 3):

Well, with closures you lose the ability to duck type on properties or to apply Javascript's built-in introspection means (`instanceof`, `isPrototypeOf`). Furthermore, a closure's free variables differ from object properties in that they are not visible in the surrounding scope. Sure, you can define getters and setters to access them, but this is a bit awkward and you still can't utilize destructuring assignment and probably other core concepts of the language.

So yes, closures and prototypes have some applications in common and even though they are not completely orthogonal to each other, they are still discrete concepts.